# How to display design on a 3D iphone in adobe illustrator

Tags: website-design, responsive-design

I want to display my responsive design using the following aproaches :-

http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Mobile-App-UX-Design.jpg

and

http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Mobile-Apps-UIUX-Design-1.jpg

i.e displaying them in a 3D wayy on a phone or just the screen.

I am using Adobe Illustrator and have tried Extrude and Bevel but it still does not come up so clearly - I guess it does not scale properly. Haven't found any good tutorial to help me out with.

Is there any other way to achieve this. Please help

Comment: This isn't a User Experience question. If you want advice on how to use Illustrator then you're better off looking for some specific Adobe Illustrator forums.

Comment: This is a graphic design question, at best. It's also not entirely clear what you are after...the sample photos really have nothing to do with extrude and bevel effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a several methods.

For your first display you need to:
1. Group your demo
2. Rotate it for 30 degrees.
3. Object > transform > Shear. 
Shear:135 degrees
Angle:205 degrees
5. Click on the preview check box to see if it fits for you. press Ok
6. Effects> stylize> Drop shadow: change only the Y offset to 44 px 
7. Duplicate the effects on the other layers.

For the i-phone display:
1. Take your i-phone photo.
2. Import your view to the same file.
3. Use the same steps in the previous tutorial: 1,2,3 and use the preview mode to feet it properly.

and that all.

also you can search for "i-phone mock-ups" its integrate well with the actions in photoshop

Good Luck,
Gal